# py2exe ImportError: No module named 'tkinter._fix'

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4, py2exe

I'm using py2exe to create my standalone executable, already tried pyinstaller, cx_freeze and even nuitka and none of these work.
The problem is py2exe raises the following error: ImportError: No module named 'tkinter._fix'

I used tkinter to build my app.

My setup file looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['BioRank.py'], options =  {'py2exe':{'packages':['numpy','tkinter','pandas','xlwt']}})
```

I'm using windows10, python 3.4 and py2exe 0.9.2.2

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue using nuitka. I solved it by adding my own logic copying missing TK / TCL parts:

```
import sys, os, subprocess, shutil
pscript = sys.argv[1]
pscript_n = pscript[:-3]
EXE = pscript_n + ".exe"

if not os.path.exists(pscript):
    raise SystemExit("Python source '%s' does not exist!" % pscript)

tk  = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix,"tcl", "tk8.6")
tcl = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix,"tcl", "tcl8.6")
if not os.path.exists(tk):
    raise SystemExit("unexpected: '%s' does not exist!" % tk)
if not os.path.exists(tcl):
    raise SystemExit("unexpected: '%s' does not exist!" % tcl)

dist_path = os.path.join("compiled", pscript_n + ".dist")
if os.path.exists(dist_path):
    print("removing old binaries ...")
    shutil.rmtree(dist_path, ignore_errors=True)

if not os.path.exists("compiled"):
    print("creating 'compiled' sub dir ...")
    os.mkdir("compiled")
    os.mkdir(os.path.join("compiled", "lib"))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join("compiled", "bin"))
    tar_tk  = os.path.join("compiled", "lib", "tk8.6")
    tar_tcl = os.path.join("compiled", "lib", "tcl8.6")
    shutil.copytree(tk, tar_tk)
    shutil.copytree(tcl, tar_tcl)
    print("'compiled' sub dir created")

print("Next messages are from Nuitka compilation.\n")

cmd = "python -m nuitka --portable --remove-output --output-dir=compiled " + pscript

subprocess.call(cmd)

copy_cmd = "xcopy /E/S/Y %s compiled\\bin" % dist_path
if os.path.exists(dist_path):
    print("".ljust(100, "-"))
    print("nuitka successful, now xcopying to compiled\\bin directory")
    print("".ljust(100, "-"))
    subprocess.call(copy_cmd)
    print("".ljust(100, "-"))
    print("'%s' should now be in '%s' and in 'compiled\\bin'\n" % (EXE, dist_path))
```

What it does:
It looks up and copies relevant TK and TCL libraries and puts them jointly in directory called "lib" alongside the one created by nuitka itself (which is called scriptname.dist). I then copy the .dist stuff over to a "run" directory.
You can repeat this script for every script you want an .exe for. They will land in the "run" directory to form a library of you own EXEs over time.

Comment: you may need to use "--standalone" in place ot "--portable" depending on your nuitka version.

Comment: do not be afraid if nuitka takes quite long for the first-ever run - it can be minutes without signs of life. Just wait, future runs will be much faster!